# How handles AES_set_encrypt_key short keys

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm writing a set of tools, where a c++ application encodes data with the AES encryption standard and a java app decodes it. As far as I know the key length has to be 16 bytes. But when I was trying to use passwords with different length I came across the following behaviour of the `AES_set_encrypt_key` function:

- length = 16 : nothing special happens, as expected
- length > 16 : password gets cut after the sixteenth character
- length < 16 : the password seems to be filled "magical"

So, does anyone know what exactly happens in the last case ?

Btw: Java throws an exception if the password is not exactly 16 chars long

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: A string has *nothing* to do with an AES key for that API. I would all-but guarantee you you're invoking undefined behavior if the octet buffer you're passing is not at least 16 bytes wide. Asking what would be the consequence would be asking for definition where there is none. If you're **un**-lucky, it *may* not fault. using a password for an AES key is  not a good move to begin with. You should be digesting that password a  thousand+ times and peeling the finale' off as the key material.

Comment: Can you show the code you were using? There is no way to pass a key longer than or shorter than the correct length to `AES_set_encrypt_key`. It doesn't take the length as a parameter. Your code probably just has a bug.

Comment: It's not really the code, it's the coder. I'm still to deep in the safe Java world to be aware of such pitfalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse byte array with C-String. Every C-String is a byte array, but not every byte array is a C-String.

The concept with AES is to use a "KEY". It acts like a password but the concept is a little bit different. It has a fixed size and must be 16 bytes on your case.

The key is a byte array of 16 bytes that is NOT a C-String. It means it can have any value at any point in the buffer, while a C-String must be null-terminated (the `'\0'` in the end of your content).

When you give a C-String to your AES, it still interprets it as a buffer, ignoring any `\0` character on the way. In other words, if your string is `"something"`, the buffer is in fact `"something\0??????"`, where "??????" here means any random trash bytes that cannot be guaranteed to work all the time.

Why does the key length < 16 is working? In debug mode, when you start a buffer, it usually keeps a default value that is repeating on your case. But it changes accordinly to compiler and/or platform, so take take.

And the key length > 16, AES is just picking the 16 first bytes of your buffer and ignoring the rest.

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution